# Can't load services inside my controller with Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I created an Angular application and added some basic code for my controller that can be seen below. I'm now trying to include two services that i created within my services.js file which is being loaded in my index.html file and required within my controllers.js file. For some reason i don't have access to either namespaces passed in, i can't seem to figure out why this is happening since i see no errors and most of the tutorials or examples i've came across show the same setup. Anyone have any ideas? Thanks :)

Controllers.js

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', ['services'])

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal, $timeout, Auth, socket) {
  // Form data for the login modal
  $scope.loginData = {};
  debugger // i dont have access to Auth or socket
  // Create the login modal that we will use later
  $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/login.html', {
    scope: $scope
  }).then(function(modal) {
    $scope.modal = modal;
  });

  // Triggered in the login modal to close it
  $scope.closeLogin = function() {
    $scope.modal.hide();
  };

  // Open the login modal
  $scope.login = function() {
    $scope.modal.show();
  };

  // Perform the login action when the user submits the login form
  $scope.doLogin = function(user) {
    console.log('Doing login', $scope.loginData);
    debugger // I dont have access to Auth or socket
    // Simulate a login delay. Remove this and replace with your login
    // code if using a login system
    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.closeLogin();
    }, 1000);
  };
})
```

Services.js

```
var baseUrl = 'http://localhost:3000';

angular.module('services', [])

.factory('socket', function socket($rootScope) {
  var socket = io(baseUrl);

  return {
    on: function(eventName, cb) {
      socket.on(eventName, function() {
        var args = arguments;
        $rootScope.$apply(function () {
          cb.apply(socket, args);
        });
      });
    },
    emit: function(eventName, data, cb) {
      socket.emit(eventName, data, function() {
        var args = arguments;
        $rootScope.$apply(function () {
          if (cb) cb.apply(socket, args);
        });
      });
    }
  };
})


.factory('Auth', function Auth($q, $http) {
  var user = null;

  var login = function login (name, password) {
    var defer = $q.defer();

    var url = baseUrl + '/login';
    var postData = { name: name, password: password };

    $http.post(url, postData).success(function(response) {
      if (response.success && response.success === true) {
        user = { name: response.name, id: response.id };
        window.localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
        return defer.resolve(response);
      } else {
        return defer.resolve('No user found');
      }
    }).error(function(err) {
      defer.reject(err);
    });

    return defer.promise;
  }

  var currentUser = function currentUser (user) {
    return user;
  }

  var logout = function logout () {
    user = null;
    window.localStorage.removeItem('user');
  }

  return {
    login: login,
    logout: logout,
    currentUser: currentUser
  };
});
```

Comment: is your code minified?

Comment: Whats the console say? Build system including service.js file in index.html?

Comment: works for me: http://plnkr.co/edit/iCAt5LaXkYpLY8Fj9qJa?p=preview

Comment: It was a problem with the environment the code was loading it. I got it working outside of Cordova.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if you've done `ng-app` and `ng-controller` in your HTML?
sample:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="starter">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Sample App</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="starter.controllers">
  <!-- Your code here -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="controller.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="service.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```